# Nancy Self Hosting - Service Unavailable - Win7

Tags: .net, nancy

I've scrapped what I was working with and went to the simplest of code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nancyHost = new Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost(new   Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
        nancyHost.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
        nancyHost.Stop();
    }
}
public class MainModule : Nancy.NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = x =>
        {
            return "Hello world!";
        };
    }
}
```

When I browse to

```
   http://localhost:8080
```

I get:

---

Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

---

I've tried several solutions.  Including several variations on: [Remote access to a Nancy Self Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548678/remote-access-to-a-nancy-self-host/8550851#8550851)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are running Visual Studio as Administrator and that `8080` is not used by something else at the same time. Have a look at the self-hosting demo which sets up a couple of different URIs for a self-hosted application https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Self/Program.cs#L12

Comment: I had tried this and it did not solve the problem.  But I took the code to another machine and tried and it worked.  So it is permissions somehow?  I'm approving the answer because either you need to run as Administrator or need to setup permissions using netsh.  But I still don't know why it won't work on this particular machine.

Comment: Running Visual Studio as administrator works for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do people think that running as Administrator is a valid option? Learn to work with the security system, not against it.

Comment: @KenRachynski do you have an answer to the question that does not require running as admin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't how much value this answer will have, but I did encounter this same 503 error when I started Nancy with this combination of settings:

```
_nancyHost = new NancyHost(new HostConfiguration { 
        RewriteLocalhost = false
    }, 
    new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}", port)));
```

The error was encountered when using a local browser accessing http://localhost:3684/ to Nancy running in a Windows Service as Local System

The prior revision with `RewriteLocalHost` on default setting of true had been working. This was one of the things I was trying while attempting to diagnose my question here: [How do I remotely access self-hosted Nancy service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559157/how-do-i-remotely-access-self-hosted-nancy-service)