# Unable to access host created by Nancy using external IP

Tags: c#, nancy

I am creating a Nancy Module that will eventually be hosted inside of a Windows Service. To start the Nancy hosting, I am using Nancy.Hosting.Self. Below is the code to start Nancy host.

```
string strHostProtocol = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostProtocol"]);
string strHostIP = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostIP"]);
string strHostPort = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostPort"]);

//Here strHostProtocol="https", strHostIP = "192.168.100.88" i.e. System IPv4, strHostPort = "9003"

var url = strHostProtocol + "://" + strHostIP + ":" + strHostPort;
//url ="https://192.168.100.88:9003"

this.host = new NancyHost(new Uri(url));
this.host.Start();
```

Now once the windows service starts, it will start the above host and I could see this in `netstat -a` command. When I browse this in browser using **`https://192.168.100.88:9003`** I will get proper response.

The problem arises when the same is browsed using its external IP. Say this system has been assigned with external IP of `208.91.158.66` and when I try browsing this as **`https://208.91.158.66:9003`** I will just get a browser default loading progress continuosly which does not stop and without any error thrown. I have also added the below command and reserved URL successfully.

`netsh http add urlacl url=https://192.168.100.88:9003/ user=everyone`

But even after this the host cannot be browsed using external IP assigned to that system. Is there any restricting Nancy is putting up? Firewalls are turned off, defenders are turned off. Anyone has any idea on this?

**UPDATE**

The duplicate linked question talks about LAN but here I am trying through external IP and I've tried answer mentioned over there and also specified the same in question

Comment: You mention firewalls, I assume this is the local OS firewall. Have you added any port forwarding on the external router?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote access to a Nancy Self Host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548678/remote-access-to-a-nancy-self-host)

Comment: Yes.. that has been done..

Comment: @TimBourguignon That question talks about `LAN` but mine through external IP and I've tried answer mentioned over there and also specified the same in question.

Comment: Chances are its only listening on 192.168.100.88 not on its remote IP.

Comment: How about with the '+' wildcard? Did you try without HTTPS? Could it have some influence here?

Comment: Have you analysed the traffic flowing in and out with Wireshark or Telrek Fiddler? It would be good to rule out firewalls, routers etc before looking at code issues (especially if it works on an internal IP).

Comment: @TimBourguignon Thank you for the suggestion, but I got solution from GitHub Issue raised by me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. This issue was also posted to **[`GitHub Nancy Repo`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2416)** and below is what @Khellang had to say.

> When you bind to `https://192.168.100.88:9003`, the
>   TcpListener/HttpListener won't listen on other interfaces. You either
>   have to bind to `https://208.91.158.66:9003` or `https://localhost:9003`
>   and set RewriteLocalhost = true (default).

Further he also said that

> If you also want to listen to requests coming to the external IP, yes.
>   Or you could use a wildcard, like `https://+:9003/`, `https://*:9003/` or
>   `https://localhost:9003/` (with **RewriteLocalhost = true**, this will
>   result in `https://+:9003/`). You can read more about them in the link I
>   posted.

and thanks to @TimBourguignon as he suggested the same in his comments. Hope this helps someone in future.

He has also suggested to read <kbd>**[`this link`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx)**</kbd> to know more about the `Strong Wildcard` and `Weak Wildcard`