# Unable to access to a nancy webservice form external connections

Tags: c#, .net, nancy, .net-standard-2.0

I have a nancy (2.0.0-clinteastwood) web service and I am unable to connect from outside.

I've tried the following solutions without success:

- https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2416
- [Remote access to a Nancy Self Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548678/remote-access-to-a-nancy-self-host)

I already have a bounding rule pointing to the specified service allowing all connections to the web service port.

I've tried the following configurations:

```
   _uri = new Uri(url);
   _hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration();
   _hostConfigs.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;
   _hostConfigs.EnableClientCertificates = true;
```

```
   _uri = new Uri(url);
   _hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration();
   _hostConfigs.RewriteLocalhost = true;
   _hostConfigs.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;
   _hostConfigs.EnableClientCertificates = true;
```

None of this has worked.

I've also tried the netsh commands but didn't work.

The web service responds perfectly to local requests the problem is with the external requests.
Previously to creating this nancy web service with .net standard I had a nancy service with .net framework and a .net core web service that responded to external requests (I had some problems since those weren't always responding).

Answer (score 0):

What is the `url` you are binding to ?

Comment: Is there firewall on your machine ? You need to allow `5000` as well.

Comment: Yes I already did It,  I also tried tot disable the firewall but it didn't work